# Get the count of nearby android cellular devices using cellular signals

Tags: java, android, mobile, bluetooth, wifi

Is it somehow possible in Android to get a count of all the nearby devices which are in active state(i.e. connected to any cellular network)? By that I mean any cellular device which is powered on and installed with a working sim.

The reason why I ask this is because whatever answers I have found so far suggest making use of bluetooth, wifi, nearby or some other custom app. My intention is to just look for devices which are actively connected to a cellular network. Each time I see a device emitting/receiving cellular signals the counter gets incremented.

I tried looking into the Android API as well but could not find something which provides this functionality. **NeighboringCellInfo** gives information about the device(and its network) on which the app is installed. And this is the closest I could get.

I was thinking that if I can get information about nearby cellular carriers then getting information about nearby cellular device should also be possible. End of the day it's about catching radio waves coming out of something.

Thank you so much for your valuable time. Really appreciate your help!

**P.S. :** I'm not very not sure if my question makes sense to you all. Please let me know if additional information is needed. I actually come from a totally different background and this is the first time i'm trying to develop a mobile app. Please feel free to correct me if my understanding is wrong.